# Supplying nav arguments during espresso tests

Tags: graph, arguments, android-espresso, code-injection, nav

I saw Stack Overflow seems to be deleting questions around this topic. No idea why..

There is nothing in the documentation around it.
I am trying to test a fragment that is part of the navigation flow and therefore has its arguments supplied by "by navArgs()" injection.

How can I supply them when launching that fragment in launchFragmentInContainer?

Answer (score 4):

Ok figured it out.
Imagine you have your arguments injected in the fragment:

```
private val args: SumArguments by navArgs()
```

And the fragment itself declared in the navigation graph:

```
 <fragment android:id="@+id/SumFragment"
        android:name="xxx"
        android:label="xxx">
        <argument
            android:name="origin"
            app:argType="SumClass"
            app:nullable="false" />
```

Then you can launch your fragmentScenario like so:

```
val origin = SumClass()

 launchFragment<SumFragment>(
            bundleOf(
                "origin" to origin,
            )
        )
```

No idea how Android knows to map Arguments from Bundle but it does. Enjoy.

Comment: I just LOVE YOU, you saved my job :D

Comment: This solution did not work for me once I'm using launchFragmentInContainer instead of launchFragment. For some reason launchFragment does not open the fragment.

Comment: @LeonardoSibela you can user launchFragmentInContainer and inside it's scope you call YourFragment.apply{ bundleof("xpto" to xpto)}. But for me the answer provided desn't work it says "has null arguments". Do i have to pass all of the arguments in the bundle?

Comment: EDIT: you can user launchFragmentInContainer like this: launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme, fragmentArgs = bundle) where "bundle" is a variable that receives bundleOf("foo" to Foo()). This works for me. Note that if you have more than one argument, you have to especify all of them in your bundle.